# How to compile a C DLL for 64 bit with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, dllimport, 32bit-64bit

I have a DLL written in C in source code. This is the code for the [General Polygon Clipper](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/alan/software/) (in case you are interested). I'm using it in a C# project via the C# wrapper provided on the homepage. This comes with a precompiled DLL.

Since switching to a 64bit Development machine with Visual Studio 2010 and Windows 7 64 bit, the application won't run anymore. This is the error I get:

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

This is because of `DLLImport`ing the 32bit `gpc.dll`, as I have gathered from stuff found on the web.

I assume this will all go away if I recompile the DLL to 64bit, but can't for the love of me figure out how to do so. My C skills are basic, in that I can write a C program with the GNU tools, but have no experience with various compilers / processors / IDEs etc.

I believe I could port this to C#. By that I mean I trust myself to actually pull it off. But I'd prefer not to, since it is a *lot* of work that I'd prefer a compiler to do for me ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be as easy as creating a new platform:

- open property pages of project (ALT+ENTER)
- choose platform *x64* in dropdown menu in top-right corner

  - if the platform does not already exist, create a new one
- rebuild

  - make sure you are checking the right artefacts when built, as you now probably have a different output directory.

Comment: The platform x64 doesn't exist, how do I create a new one? I have a C++/MFC project in VS2010. I couldn't find platform x64 or 0x86 anywhere in the project settings.

Comment: With Visual Studio 2010 Express, 64 bits SDK is not included. You need to [download it separately and install it](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279). I had too many issues with it and was actually able to have a correct installation on one computer, by accident. Since then, I'm unable to repeat an installation from scratch. I'll check GCC (which I think now works better than Visual compiler).