# How to compile a 64-bit dll written in C?

Tags: c, dll, compilation, 64-bit, x86-64

I have a Java program which makes use of some native function calls to speed up video encoding. It requires a DLL, which I will write in C (I have just a test one right now).

When I compile the DLL with `cl /I "java-path/include" /"java-path/include/win32" -DL -ML Main.c -FeTest.dll` it compiles, but I get a 32-bit DLL. After I did some research on the internet, I found out that I would need a 64-bit DLL instead.

After more research, I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060452/how-to-compile-a-c-dll-for-64-bit-with-visual-studio-2010#3061864) which is the only one for C (even C++ was hard to find), but this only works if you are writing/building via Visual Studio 2010. I am using Elipse for the Java, CLion for the C, and compiling via the "Developer Command Prompt." so this does not work for me. How might I recompile as a 64-bit DLL?

EDIT: I am using the `cl.exe` that comes with Visual Studio 2017

UPDATE: I found the 64-bit `cl.exe` under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe`, however when running it, I get an error that the library machine type (x86) conflicts with the target type (x64). How do I change the library machine type?

Comment: @jdv It ignores it, so no

Comment: @c0degreen Not duplicate, but related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548138/how-to-compile-x64-code-with-visual-studio-in-command-line

Comment: @jdv I must clarify, it is the Visual Studio compiler (cl.exe). Do you know of an alternative I could use?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and be clear what toolchain you are using.

Comment: Are you using a developer command prompt, or an x64 native tools command prompt?

Comment: @RetiredNinja The "Developer Command Prompt for VC 2017"

Comment: Use the x64 prompt.

Comment: I cant find where that is. Do you know?

Comment: On my system, there are several choices in Programs / Visual Studio Tools / Windows Desktop Command Prompts.

Comment: @prl, I found the 84-bit version of cl.exe uder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\Hostx64\x64, however when I run it i get what I added in the update

Comment: *vcvarsall.bat* (`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" amd64` - the *VC2017* location is a bit odd) is the file that will set all the appropriate env vars for building on different architectures from command line. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450813/how-to-build-a-dll-version-of-libjpeg-9b/44469099#44469099 (in the 1st part I explain how to use it).  Regarding the error in the last comment, just delete the  *.obj* file and re-run the command.

Comment: @CristiFati please add that as an answer, as it fixed my problems. Thanks sooo much!

Comment: Glad to hear that! Just one sec, as I'm preparing a small (and dummy) example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile x64 code with Visual Studio in command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548138/how-to-compile-x64-code-with-visual-studio-in-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained at the beginning of [[SO]: How to build a DLL version of libjpeg 9b? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450813/how-to-build-a-dll-version-of-libjpeg-9b/44469099#44469099) (bullets from **1. Prepare the ground** section), there are different ways to deal with building from command line in *VStudio*. 
I'm going to focus on *vcvarsall.bat*. More details on [[MSDN]: Setting the Path and Environment Variables for Command-Line Builds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt(v=vs.140).aspx) (It's *VStudio2015* as *VStudio2017* link is broken). 
I prepared a dummy example.

*code.c*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "jni.h"


__declspec(dllexport) int func() {
    JavaVMInitArgs args;
    printf("Pointer size: %lld bits\n", sizeof(void*) * 8);
    printf("JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs returned: %d\n", JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(&args));
    return 0;
}
```

**Build**:

> ```
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050164687>"c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2017\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
> **********************************************************************
> ** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.6.6
> ** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
> **********************************************************************
> [vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050164687>dir /b
> code.c
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050164687>cl /nologo /LD /I"c:\Install\x64\Oracle\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\include" /I"c:\Install\x64\Oracle\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\include\win32" /DWIN64 /DWIN32 code.c /link /LIBPATH:"c:\Install\x64\Oracle\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\lib" /OUT:dummy.dll jvm.lib
> code.c
>    Creating library code.lib and object code.exp
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050164687>dir /b
> code.c
> code.exp
> code.lib
> code.obj
> dummy.dll
> ```

**Notes**:

- My *vcvarsall* path is custom, because I installed *VStudio2017* under "*C:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2017*". Default path is "*%SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community*"
- After running *vcvarsall*, I don't have to specify to *cl.exe* (or *link.exe*):

  - The full path
  - Build options (architecture specific, including paths)
  - I still have to specify things that it doesn't know about (like *Java* stuff)
- In order to test the newly built *.dll*, I'm going to use *Python*, as it's easier than writing another *.c* program that uses it
- Since I linked the *.dll* to *jvm.lib*, at runtime it will need *jvm.dll*, so I'm adding its path into *%PATH%*
- I built my code with *VStudio2017* (*VCRuntime14.0*), but *jvm.dll* is linked to *VCRuntime10.0* (*VStudio2010*), meaning that there will be (at least) 2 *VCRuntime*s loaded in my program. That is to be avoided as it could lead to all kinds of nasty problems

> ```
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050164687>set PATH=%PATH%;c:\Install\x64\Oracle\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\bin\server
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050164687>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe"
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> import ctypes
> >>> dummy = ctypes.CDLL("dummy.dll")
> >>> dummy.func()
> Pointer size: 64 bits
> JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs returned: -1
> 0
> >>>
> ```