# Call function by URL in Flask

Tags: python, url, flask, dll, ctypes

I have a C++ DLL. I want to make a **Flask** server to call the functions in this DLL. So I use `ctypes` inside `Flask`. Here is my code in `views.py`:

```
from flask import render_template
from MusicServer_Flask import app
from ctypes import *
import os

#load Dll:
cppdll = CDLL("C:\\VS_projects\\MusicServer_Flask\\NetServerInterface.dll")

#wrapping DLL function：
initnetwork = getattr(cppdll, "?InitNetwork@@YAHQAD0H@Z") #The function can be accessed successfully
initnetwork.argtypes = [c_char_p,c_char_p,c_int]
initnetwork.restype = wintypes.BOOL

#define route:
@app.route('/InitNetwork/<LocalIP>/<ServerIP>/<LocalDeviceID>')
def InitNetwork(LocalIP, ServerIP, LocalDeviceID):
    return initnetwork(LocalIP, ServerIP, LocalDeviceID)
```

With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50325050/ctypes-argumenterror-when-calling-dll-functions-with-python), I can call this function in Python interactice window successfully using this:`InitNetwork(b"192.168.1.101",b"192.168.1.101",555)`:
[image] However, when I run the Flask project and enter this route:`http://192.168.1.102:8081/InitNetwork/b"192.168.1.102"/b"22192.168.1.102"/555` It gives me an error like this:
[image]
It seems that the `b"192.168.1.102"` becomes `b%22192.168.1.102%22` in the requested URL. Why this happens? How can I use the right URL to call this function?

Thank you for your attention.

**Edit:**

Thanks to @Paula Thomas 's answer, I think I moved one step towards the answer.I changed the code as below to convert the first and second input parameters into bytes:

```
@app.route('/InitNetwork/<LocalIP>/<ServerIP>/<LocalDeviceID>')
def InitNetwork(LocalIP, ServerIP, LocalDeviceID):
    b_LocalIP = bytes(LocalIP,'utf-8')
    b_ServerIP = bytes(ServerIP,'utf-8')
    return initnetwork(b_LocalIP, b_ServerIP, LocalDeviceID)
```

However, neither `http://172.16.4.218:8081/InitNetwork/172.16.4.218/172.16.4.218/555` nor `http://172.16.4.218:8081/InitNetwork/"172.16.4.218"/"172.16.4.218"/555` works. Still gives me `wrong type` error. Would somebody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find that Flask is passing you strings (type str) whereas your C or C++ function is expecting bytes (hence the 'b' before two of the parameters) for the first two parameters and an int for the third. It is your responsibility to convert them.

Comment: I agree. But I don't know how to convert the input variable into bytes. Could you give me some hints?

Comment: According to your suggestion, I have updated my post.

Comment: But you still haven't changed the last parameter to an int from a str.

Comment: It turns out that I should return a string like `return str(initnetwork(d_LocalIP,d_ServerIP,DeviceID))`. And it give me the right result